# Proper Syntax For Lua Code Inside Terminal

Tags: json, terminal, lua, lua-table

I am using Lua version 54 inside my windows 64 bit OS. I am struggling writing the proper syntax for opening a directory, then opening the local file with path. Then once the file is open (JSON File) converting it to Lua Table.
Code I am using:
Lua54 syntax

```
local archhudbasic = io.open("C:\\Users\\Lichr\\Documents",)
```

Internal functions

```
    local function kind_of(obj)
        if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return type(obj) end
    local i = 1
        for _ in pairs(obj) do
        if obj[i] ~= nil then i = i + 1 else return 'table' end
    end
        if i == 1 then return 'table' else return 'array' end
    end

    local function escape_str(s)
    local in_char  = {'\\', '"', '/', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t'}
    local out_char = {'\\', '"', '/',  'b',  'f',  'n',  'r',  't'}
        for i, c in ipairs(in_char) do s = s:gsub(c, '\\' .. out_char[i])
    end
    return s
    end
```

Returns pos, did_find; there are two cases:

1. Delimiter found: pos = pos after leading space + delim; did_find = true.
2. Delimiter not found: pos = pos after leading space;     did_find = false.
   This throws an error if err_if_missing is true and the delim is not found.

```
    local function skip_delim(str, pos, delim, err_if_missing)
        pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)
        if str:sub(pos, pos) ~= delim then
        if err_if_missing then
        error('Expected ' .. delim .. ' near position ' .. pos)
     end
     return pos, false
     end
     return pos + 1, true
     end
```

Expects the given pos to be the first character after the opening quote.
Returns val, pos; the returned pos is after the closing quote character.

```
    local function parse_str_val(str, pos, val)
        val = val or ''
    local early_end_error = 'End of input found while parsing string.'
        if pos > #str then error(early_end_error) end
    local c = str:sub(pos, pos)
        if c == '"'  then return val, pos + 1 end
        if c ~= '\\' then return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1, val .. c) end
    -- We must have a \ character.
    local esc_map = {b = '\b', f = '\f', n = '\n', r = '\r', t = '\t'}
    local nextc = str:sub(pos + 1, pos + 1)
        if not nextc then error(early_end_error) end
    return parse_str_val(str, pos + 2, val .. (esc_map[nextc] or nextc))
    end
```

Returns val, pos; the returned pos is after the number's final character.

```
    local function parse_num_val(str, pos)
    local num_str = str:match('^-?%d+%.?%d*[eE]?[+-]?%d*', pos)
    local val = tonumber(num_str)
        if not val then error('Error parsing number at position ' .. pos .. '.') end
    return val, pos + #num_str
    end
```

Public values and functions.

```
    function json.stringify(obj, as_key)
    local s = {}  -- We'll build the string as an array of strings to be concatenated.
    local kind = kind_of(obj)  -- This is 'array' if it's an array or type(obj) 
    otherwise.
        if kind == 'array' then
        if as_key then error('Can\'t encode array as key.') end
        s[#s + 1] = '['
    for i, val in ipairs(obj) do
        if i > 1 then s[#s + 1] = ', ' end
        s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(val)
    end
    s[#s + 1] = ']'
        elseif kind == 'table' then
        if as_key then error('Can\'t encode table as key.') end
    s[#s + 1] = '{'
    for k, v in pairs(obj) do
        if #s > 1 then s[#s + 1] = ', ' end
        s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(k, true)
        s[#s + 1] = ':'
        s[#s + 1] = json.stringify(v)
    end
        s[#s + 1] = '}'
        elseif kind == 'string' then
    return '"' .. escape_str(obj) .. '"'
        elseif kind == 'number' then
        if as_key then return '"' .. tostring(obj) .. '"' end
    return tostring(obj)
    elseif kind == 'boolean' then
    return tostring(obj)
    elseif kind == 'nil' then
    return 'null'
    else
    error('Unjsonifiable type: ' .. kind .. '.')
    end
    return table.concat(s)
    end

    json.null = {}  //This is a one-off table to represent the null value.

    function json.parse(str, pos, end_delim)
    pos = pos or 1
    if pos > #str then error('Reached unexpected end of input.') end
    local pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)  -- Skip whitespace.
    local first = str:sub(pos, pos)
    if first == '{' then  -- Parse an object.
    local obj, key, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
        key, pos = json.parse(str, pos, '}')
        if key == nil then return obj, pos end
        if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between object items.') end
        pos = skip_delim(str, pos, ':', true)  -- true -> error if missing.
        obj[key], pos = json.parse(str, pos)
        pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
    elseif first == '[' then  -- Parse an array.
    local arr, val, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
        val, pos = json.parse(str, pos, ']')
        if val == nil then return arr, pos end
        if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between array items.') end
        arr[#arr + 1] = val
        pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
    elseif first == '"' then  -- Parse a string.
    return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1)
    elseif first == '-' or first:match('%d') then  -- Parse a number.
    return parse_num_val(str, pos)
    elseif first == end_delim then  -- End of an object or array.
    return nil, pos + 1
    else  -- Parse true, false, or null.
    local literals = {['true'] = true, ['false'] = false, ['null'] = json.null}
    for lit_str, lit_val in pairs(literals) do
        local lit_end = pos + #lit_str - 1
        if str:sub(pos, lit_end) == lit_str then return lit_val, lit_end + 1 end
    end
    local pos_info_str = 'position ' .. pos .. ': ' .. str:sub(pos, pos + 10)
        error('Invalid json syntax starting at ' .. pos_info_str)
    end
    end

    return json
```

I am new to lua coding. What am I missing? How can I make this code functional inside the terminal?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not reinventing the wheel and using an existing `json` encode/decode library, using something like `luarocks`, for instance? Main website: https://luarocks.org/ and possible JSON implementations: https://luarocks.org/search?q=json

Comment: `local archhudbasic = io.open("C:\\Users\\Lichr\\Documents",)` - clear syntax error here: trailing comma in the argument list